# Overlapped/stacked range bar chart using HighCharts

Tags: javascript, c#, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to create an overlapped bar chart using HighCharts to replace a server-side charting solution (which renders an image). The problem is that I need a form of overlapped/ranged bar chart (it won't actually overlap though), and a series can have more than one range and all series should be plotted on the same "line", and I'm not finding any example which is similar to what I need.

Here is a picture of the chart created using the current server-side logic:
[image: Ranged bar chart]

You can see that I have multiple series: "Extra", "Normal", Atraso", etc. And the same series can have multiple ranges: Normal = [09:00-11:40],[13:00-18:48]; Extra: [12:45-13:00],[18:48-19:48]

And it is not limited to 2 ranges per series.

I'm at a loss figuring out how to do that in HighCharts! In the current server-side solution I just add a SeriesPoint object for each range:

```
theSeries.Points.Add(new SeriesPoint("Extra", start, end));
```

Is there a way to do that in HighCharts without resorting to drawing primitives?

Comment: I would try out columnrage typ series instead of stacking, or use [gantt](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/804783-gantt-chart) type. Stacking won't allow you to overlap points.

Comment: @PawełFus in the current solution I actually do the "stacking" by hand, as I set the min and max values based on the data so that is fits the whole chart area as in the ample chart image. I think that you're right and columnrange is the only option that could give me the desired effect. I can have multiple ranges for a series, and now I'm trying to figure out how to have multiple series on the same columnrange chart and render them on the same "line" so that the legend works. If I can figure it out I'll probably make the move to HighCharts!

Comment: When using columnrange, you can set for each of the points `x` position, like this: `data: [ [x, from_1, to_1], [x, from_1, to_2] ]`. Simply use the same `x` to render column ranges at the same place. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yhcxnyyw/ (you can use one series for all of the points - just set for each of them separate color: http://jsfiddle.net/yhcxnyyw/1/ - but you probably prefer separate series).

Comment: @PawełFus your first suggestion was the key for me to find a way, your second put me in the right track! I also needed a separate item in the legend for each "color", then I found the name property... Here is a fiddle that has everything I need thanks to you: http://jsfiddle.net/n23cb2hc/1/